# how to send object using postman rest client to call REST service

Tags: java, json, rest, postman

This is my request URL - 
https://api100.abc.com:9443/aa/bb/rest/**getList**

I am hitting this URL using POSTMAN REST Client. In header tab I have added "{"Content-Type":"application/json"}" and in Body tab in raw section I have added my JSON object -

```
{
"tokenID": "10503010",
"resultType1": 3,
"resultType2": 4,
"scCode": 1
}
```

I have added one pojo class BankParam and in that class I have added tokenID, resultType1, resultType2, scCode as variables.

My REST service code is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getList", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ApiOperation(value="Retrieves list of banks")
public List<Bank> getBankList (BankParam bankParam){

    System.out.println(bankParam.getTokenID());

}
```

In the above code I am getting null value as `bankParam` object is empty. I want to pass this object using POSTMAN client. Please help me out. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `RequestBody` annotation just before the parameter.

```
@PostMapping(value="/getList")
@ApiOperation(value="Retrieves list of banks")
public List<Bank> getBankList (@RequestBody BankParam bankParam){
    System.out.println(bankParam.getTokenID());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your REST code as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getList", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ApiOperation(value="Retrieves list of banks")
public List<Bank> getBankList (@RequestBody BankParam bankParam){

    System.out.println(bankParam.getTokenID());

}
```